# NServicebus- subscriber not receiving messages

Tags: nservicebus, subscriber

I have publisher and subscriber implemented using nservice bus 4.4.2 version. Subscriber is not receiving the message.

I can see subscription in the publisher subscription, enabled debug trace of nservicebus and publisher log says that message is sent, but subscriber is not receiving the message.

Is there any other ways to trouble shoot the issue? The subscribe application is able to receive other subscription messages from other applications.

MSMQ is used as transport and in memory storage is used.

Any inputs are appreciated

thanks,
Kedar.

Comment: If you switch to another type of persistence, you will be able to see if the subscription exists and also the contents of the subscription.  I would try that first to see if the subscription exists and contains the correct information.

Comment: Is the assembly containing the message defintions versionned or strongly named?

Comment: The problem is happening because the version of the contracts dll in publisher is different from the subscriber. Is there any way to tell nservicebus to ignore version. And the debug logs of nservicebus won't mention this and they say the message is sent.

Comment: @user2745257 By different version, do you mean that there are breaking changes between the two versions? If so, best practice would dictate that you create a new type to represent the new version, keep the handler for the Vn-1 version around, introduce a Vn version of the handler to deal with your new contract and then bring the versions in line across both publisher and subscriber before deprecating the Vn-1 handler. With regards to the message being sent successfully, that's expected behaviour. MSMQ does not care whether a recipient can handle a message.